# MongoDB: aggregation $lookup between ObjectIds returning an empty array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to perform an aggregation using $lookup between two fields of type `ObjectId`. I've already checked my data and it should be returning something. Also, the schemas indeed define the fields as ObjectId, so if I am not mistaken I should not need to convert the data type as I've seen in some posts. Here's my query:

```
db.workerlocationcontexts.aggregate([ 
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "LocationSensors",
            localField: "sensor",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "test"
        }
    }
])
```

Here are my collections/sample data:

- `WorkerLocationContexts`

  ```
  {
    "_id":{"$oid":"615676c885ccad55a493503b"},
    "updatedAt":{"$date":"2021-10-01T02:47:36.207Z"},
    "createdAt":{"$date":"2021-10-01T02:47:36.207Z"},
    "sensor":{"$oid":"6181e5f83fca98374cf901fd"},
    "worker":{"$oid":"6153dcfb58ad722c747eb42d"},
    "__v":0
  }
  ```
- `LocationSensor`

  ```
  {
    "_id":{"$oid":"6181e5f83fca98374cf901fd"},
    "name":"Location Sensor 1",
    "description":"Location sensor for Location 2",
    "location": "$oid":"6181df3b3fca98374cf901fb"},
    "trackerType":"RFID",
    "sensorType":"ENVIRONMENT",
    "type":"LOCATION",
    "__v":0
  }
  ```

The result I'm getting are all my `WorkerLocationContexts`, but the field "test" returns as an empty array.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the collection name and ensure is `LocationSensors`. Or change the lookup to colletction name, maybe `locationsensors`. The query [should works](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mKujMdbIogl)

Comment: Hi @J.F., you are right! The collection name was correct, but apparently it is case sensitive! Just changed the letters and it worked... Can you post it as an answer so I can set it as solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`from` field into `$lookup` seems to be case sensitive so it is a common problem the collection name typed in that field.

One common problem is not add the final "s" while using mongoose. Os, as in this case, the use of capital letters, yo using `from: locationsensors` should works like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mKujMdbIogl)

The `from` field has to be the same as the collection name, otherwise Mongo can't find the desired collection.